# how to get rid of weight fragments

Tags: 3d-view, bones, weight-painting, pose-mode, weight-paint-mode

so i used the gradient tool in weight painting  to get this middle finger bone some weight. but the gradient applied to all the other fingers (if you know how to stop that from happening i would appreciate that as well.) so i manually erased it all with the brush tool and there are tiny invisible fragments of weight all over the fingers. how do i get rid of them?
[image: finger bone]
[image: weight error]
[image: in weight painting mode]
[image: alt angle]

blend file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gKpBu4aaT7PBCBHUR3I766Gy59YjzRN4/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subtract these vertices from the vertex group. In the brush settings choose *Blend > Subtract, Weight > 1*, under *Advanced* disable *Front Faces Only*, choose *Falloff Shape > Projected*, make sure that *Front Face Falloff* is disabled, then paint:

[image]

Also it looks like you have floating vertices, you should remove them.

Comment: how do i remove floating vertices (I'm not the one who made the model)

Comment: I guess you need to select all in Edit mode then in the header menu > Mesh > Clean Up > Delete Loose